# Exporting jupyter notebook to pdf with offline plotly graph; missing graphs

Tags: python, pdf, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I am trying to create pdf export of my lesson plans and I use plotly offline for the graphs. In a MWE below, the plot will display in the Jupyter Notebook but will not show up when I export to pdf. I export using `File-->Download as-->PDF via Latex (.pdf)`.

I'd like to make a pdf instead of using html. I understand it might take an extra step to convert an html export to pdf, but I was just wondering if there was a more direct route (a code modification?) that would allow me to export directly through `File-->Download as-->PDF via Latex (.pdf)`

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import plotly.graph_objs as go

data = [go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[3, 2, 1])
]
iplot(data)
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to specify the appropriate [Default Renderer](https://plotly.com/python/renderers/#setting-the-default-renderer) (or Renderers, if you want to visualize it in the Notebook and also when exporting to PDF using the `File-->Download as-->PDF via Latex (.pdf)` option you mentioned).

I have been struggling with this myself for some hours too, but the setup that ended up working for me is the following:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = "notebook+pdf"  # Renderer for Notebook and HTML exports + Renderer for PDF exports
# init_notebook_mode(connected=True)  # Do not include this line because it may not work
```

Note that you can concatenate as many Renderers as you want using the `+` symbol, and Plotly will [magically know](https://plotly.com/python/renderers/#multiple-renderers) when to use each of them.

Comment: hm. This looks promising, but I couldn't get it to download as pdf via latex. Would you mind posting a solution that includes the code from my MWE and confirm that you can download as pdf via latex with no problems?

Comment: Super! The "init_noteook_mode" was the culprit all the time. Thank for letting us know. It worked after I commented the line! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I think because plotly graphs are svg objects and generated by javascript, I dont have export to PDF working in my jupyter notebook, so I was unable to check and confirm my answer.

Plotly offline does not have show as image, you can use plotly online to do this, its free to generate graphs,

You need to create an online account, also you need to paste the username and API key from plotly website (API key can be found in settings).

> **Note: please check in plotly if the plots are shared in public or private, I am not responsible for your plots becoming public.**

Anyway this will give you an image output of the graph, and you can export it to PDF

**Code:**

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go

plotly.plotly.sign_in('<<username goes here>>', '<<api key goes here>>')
trace = go.Bar(x=[2, 4, 6], y= [10, 12, 15])
data = [trace]
layout = go.Layout(title='A Simple Plot', width=800, height=640)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

plotly.plotly.image.save_as(fig, filename='a-simple-plot.png')

from IPython.display import Image
Image('a-simple-plot.png')
```

Comment: you are only taking the static image, did you manage to also export interactivity to pdf some how?

Comment: @PaariVendhan The interactivity is cause of javascript, PDF cannot have Javascript embedded!

Comment: I am not saying pdf should have javascript, but some how transfer the interactivity to a form acceptable inside pdf. For eg, tikz pgfplots has clickable functionalities.

Comment: @PaariVendhan GO raise this enhancement with plotly and see their response, Thanks!

Comment: Its clearly out of scope for plotly and also webgl. It is up to either ipython or to us.

Comment: @PaariVendhan You seem to be the expert, all the best finding it!

Comment: Dude, why so much negativity and hate? All I asked was if you found a way around that as well. It is a platform for discussing various method. If you want to withdraw just with one counter argument fine. Up to you. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a solution for the exact original problem above. However, if you wish to consider the .html format, here is a nice solution that worked for me. After all, my goal was just to share the notebook with people who didn't have `jupyter` installed.

The conversion to `.html` is performed with [plotlyhtmlexporter](https://github.com/plotly/plotlyhtmlexporter).
Here is a piece of code you can copy-paste:

```
  pip install plotlyhtmlexporter
  jupyter nbconvert --to plotlyhtml mynotebook.ipynb
```

You might then want to try and save (print) the .html from your browser as a .pdf, but I think it would be equivalent to just printing the original notebook to .pdf. As I say, in my case, having a jupyter-independent .html file was enough.

Answer (score 1):

A bit easier solution is to use `image_bytes = fig.to_image(format='png')` and than display using `Image(image_bytes)`, but firstly you should install [`orca`](https://github.com/plotly/orca), and 
 `pip3 install psutil requests` 
example:

```
fig = go.Figure()
""" here goes some code to draw """

image_bytes = fig.to_image(format='png', , width=1200, height=700, scale=1) # you can use other formats as well (like 'svg','jpeg','pdf')

#instead of using fig.show()
from IPython.display import Image
Image(img_bytes)
```

You can read more [here](https://plot.ly/python/static-image-export/)

Than you can convert it with `File -> Download as -> PDF` or using terminal `jupyter nbconvert --to pdf <notebook_name>.ipynb`

Comment: Hi Dima Zhylko. Please consider adding more information because if the links become obsolete, then you have a very low quality answer.

Comment: Thank you, @TiagoMartinsPeres

Answer (score 1):

Just use this and download the notebook as PDF via HTML. Also you need to pip install kaleido first.

```
    import plotly.io as pio
    pio.kaleido.scope.default_format = "png"
```