# Plotly: How to export only active legend when exporting plotly graph as png?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I have a plotly graph with more than 80 individual traces:
[image: Plotly png export of all traces]

Now I want to export a png with only a few active traces like this:
[image: This is a screenshot of what I want it to look like]

But when I export the image with the plotly camera icon it shows the top of the legend and not the legend of the active traces:
[image: Actual export with plotly]

My question is, is there a way to tell plotly to export the graph with only the active trace legends visible?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty interesting. If you use the [approch described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59815797/how-to-save-plotly-express-plot-into-a-html-or-static-image-file/59819140#59819140), and run

```
fig.write_image("yourfile.png")
```

...then you'll get the original `fig` object with all traces included. Even after subsetting the series through the legend.

But if you use the `camera icon` on the toolbar, then you'll get the edited version as a `.png` file.

[image]

Comment: Hello, may I ask a follow up question? Is it possible to export only the legend of the active traces? Like, in this example, only NFLX and MSFT?