# How to export a dashbio graph

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Is there a way to save [dashbio graphs](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-bio/)? (other than just taking a screenshot)

- For example, plotly has "download plot" button, and [also a way to do it with code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59815797),
- `dash_cytoscape` has [its own way](https://dash.plotly.com/cytoscape/images) like this:

```py
import dash_cytoscape as cyto
cyto.load_extra_layouts()  # enable svg export
@app.callback(
    Output("<element-id>", "generateImage"),
# ... other steps follow
```

- However, I can't find a way to save a `dashbio` graph, either in gui, or with code.

Comment: [`dash_bio.NglMoleculeViewer`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-bio/nglmoleculeviewer#saving-an-image) has an option to save an image. [`dash_bio.Circos`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-bio/circos#circos-properties) has `"enableDownloadSVG"`. But what about other dashbio graphs in general?